# Can you search items in the Recycle Bin exclusively

Tags: search, content, recycle-bin

Is there any way to search for content ONLY within the Recycle Bin in SharePoint 2013?  I'm not a programmer... need a novice solution.

Comment: Other than sorting by the name field, no, there isn't anything you can do without code of some sort

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you can do it OOTB/ or view search service application.
But if you know the Item title then you can use SharePoint powershell to find it.

```
(Get-SPSite "http://SERVERNAME:PORT/").RecycleBin | ?{$_.Title -match "DeletedFile"}
```

if you want to restore it then

```
(Get-SPSite "http://SERVERNAME:PORT").RecycleBin.Restore("e7652991-b3b7-4df2-a3c8-39b76a8e98d3")
```

Source: [Get files / search files from Recycle Bin - SharePoint 2010](http://markviky.blogspot.com/2010/12/get-files-search-files-from-recycle-bin.html)